Finding Weight Differentials in Differential Neural Network
I am implementing a Neural Network from scratch that trains on standard Labels $(Y)$ and Differential Labels $(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} = \bar{X})$. This involves using a cost function
$C = (\alpha \cdot MSE_Y) + (\beta \cdot MSE_{\bar{X}})$
The approach I've taken is to differentiate this piecewise, starting with $\frac{\partial(\beta \cdot MSE_{\bar{X}})}{\partial W_L}$.
For example for $L=3$ I begin using AD and the chain rule to find:
$\frac{\partial(\beta \cdot MSE_{\bar{Y}})}{\partial W_3}$. = $\frac{2\beta}{n}(\hat{\bar{X}} - \bar{X})\cdot\frac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial W_3}$
The issue for me arises when I attempt to differentiate $\frac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial W_3}$
$\frac{\partial \bar{X}}{\partial W_3} = \frac{\partial \bar{A_0}}{\partial W_3} = \frac{\partial \bar{A_0}}{\partial \bar{Z_1}} \cdot \frac{\partial \bar{Z_1}}{\partial \bar{A_1}} \cdot \frac{\partial \bar{A_1}}{\partial \bar{Z_1}} \cdot \frac{\partial \bar{Z_1}}{\partial \bar{A_2}} \cdot \frac{\partial \bar{A_2}}{\partial W_3} = W_1 ^\top \odot [\sigma^\prime(Z_1) \cdot W_2 ^\top \odot [\sigma^\prime(Z_2) \cdot \frac{\partial \bar{A_2}}{\partial W_3}]]$
However, here the order of the derivative $\frac{\partial \bar{A_2}}{\partial W_3}$ does not match when the product rule is used.
$\bar{A_2} =  W_3^\top \cdot \sigma^\prime(Z_3) = W_3^\top \cdot \sigma^\prime(W_3 \cdot A_2 + B_3)$
and for the derivative I get:
$\frac{\partial \bar{A_2}}{\partial W_3} = \frac{\partial W_3^\top}{\partial W_3}\bar{Z_3} + W_3^\top\frac{\partial \bar{Z_3}}{\partial W_3} = \sigma^\prime(Z_3) + W_3^\top[\sigma^{\prime\prime}(Z_3)A_2^\top]$
In this product rule, the order of the 2 added terms does not align. From here, I do not know how to work backwards from this result to get $\frac{\partial(\beta \cdot MSE_{\bar{Y}})}{\partial W_3}$ and as such, do not know how to get a derivative to update my weight matrices and train my networks.
I would really appreciate any advice on how to calculate these differentials.
I've also attached a handwritten derivation of the structure of the network here that includes the values of the adjoints for a sample network.
